# Why is std::thread blocking execution?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I want to have a class method running in a separate thread :

```
std::thread myThread(&Class::method, this);
myThread.join();
//Other events
```

While doing this, the other events occur only when the Class:method is over, not simultaneously.

What did I forget ?

Comment: The `join` call blocks until the thread has finished. Do something between the thread creation and its `join` call.

Comment: Whatever code you want to execute simultaneously should be between the thread constructor and join. You don't have any.

Comment: You're calling `join` on the thread. What makes you do that? Have you read some [docs for `join`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join)? Or is this just random code you copy-pasted from somewhere and expect to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling `.join`() on the thread, which blocks until that thread has finished, to run things concurrently with that thread either call `join()` after everything else that you want to run concurrently has finished, or call `detach()` on the thread object instead

---

For example

```
auto th = std::thread{[]() { ... }};
do_something();
th.join();
```

Here in this example `do_something()` will run concurrently with the thread `th`, or you can call `detach()`

```
std::thread{[]() { ... }}.detach();
do_something();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what happens:

1. Start a thread and have it run &Class::method

   `std::thread myThread(&Class::method, this);`
2. Wait until the thread has ended.

   `myThread.join();`
3. Do other things in the curren thread

   `//Other events`

As you can see, your `myThread.join()` pauses your current thread.

Do it like this instead:

```
std::thread myThread(&Class::method, this);
//Other events
myThread.join();
```

Alternatively; don't perform that join and call [myThread.detach();](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach) instead.

Comment: The trouble is that my program crashes while calling .detach(), is it because I call elements from the Class in the method ? (like this->value ?)

Comment: @sh5164 I don't know what your code does, so that is impossible to answer. Possibly you have race conditions, or your current thread deletes the instance that your other thread is working on etc. You could perform the .join() after all your other stuff instead, as my edit suggests too.